# How to copy data from a CSV file opened in Excel, into a Word table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, copy-paste, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2016

I'm using MS Office 2016, and I have a CSV file 2 columns, that I wish to copy into an existing table within Word, also with 2 columns, i.e. a 1 to 1 paste from Excel to Word, following with the destination cell formatting.

I've tried copy-pasting, but none of the paste options give me the desired result.
"Nest table" pastes the 2 source columns into a single destination cell.
"Merge table" creates a new destination table with different column widths/formatting where the mouse cursor is in Word.
"Insert as new rows", I don't even know what it does, but the borders are no longer there and the widths are wrong as well.
"Keep text only" again pastes the 2 source columns into a single destination cell.

Comment: I often find it better to make it look good in Excel, then copy the image using 'Snipping Tool' and pasting into Word like that, so Word can't mess with the formatting.

Answer (score 1):

Insert a new row in your Word table, select the 2 columns (empty cells) and do a 'Merge Table'. Then just reapply the formatting to the new cells. In my example, they didn't align center as the pre-existing values.

[image: My examples - a 2 col CSV and a 2 col table in word]